# ValueError when running Docker - File path...is not a valid file or url (works fine locally)

Tags: python, windows, docker, debugging, pdf

I have a python RAG script that works fine locally (Windows).

When I run it with docker:

```
ValueError: File path ./data/text.pdf is not a valid file or url
```

I am using

```
loader = PyPDFLoader("./data/text.pdf")
```

in basic_rag.py

This is the file structure:

```
APP
 chroma
 data
   text.pdf
 .env
 .gitignore
 basic_rag
 Dockerfile
 requirements.txt
 style
```

This is the Dockerfile code

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /rag-test

COPY . /data  . /data/
COPY ./basic_rag.py ./main.py

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

I have been investigating similar posts but cannot find the answer.

Thanks for the orientation.

Comment: Your first `COPY` command has too many spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the first `COPY` statement. There is an additional space.
try this **dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /rag-test

COPY ./data  ./data/
COPY ./basic_rag.py ./main.py

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```